# LinearLayout or ListItem for showing list of items in a scrollable view?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-view

Say I have an activity showing informations on an object: the name, a little description, a photo. Below this informations I have a list of comments. Obviously the number of comments displayed is not fixed and the list have to be created dynamically. Now I want ALL the activity layout to be scrollable, so I added a ScrollView as parent of all other Views. But in this way, I can't use a ListView to show the comments, because it's not possible (or it's very discouraged) to wrap a ListView inside a ScrollView. I'm compelled to use a LinearLayout, cycling on the comments list and inflating (I want to keep layouts in xml) multiple times the same layout, which brings to other drawbacks like the confusion on items ids.
Note well that even trying to reduce the complexity showing a prefixed number of items in the list (say showing N most recent), it would be very annoying to embed in the xml definition of the LinearLayout a fixed number of list items, because changes in N would affect both code and xml.

Which could be a optimum design to face all this problems:

1. Keep all the activity layout scrollable.
2. List a variable non pre-fixed number of items in a portion of the UI.
3. Keep the definition of the list item layout in the xml.
4. Prevent inflating multiple times the same layout.

I can't figure out that in android it is not possible or it's necessary to use some kind of workaround to achieve this common behavior.

Comment: I had a similar Activity in my app. My approach was to use a scroll view and limit the comments to 2 and something like click to see all comments. But I decided to go this way because the rest of the layout(other than comments) is a huge thing, comments are like `1.5 x ScreenHeight` below, at the bottom.

Comment: You mean 1.5% of screenHeight?

Comment: No, comments are the last in my layout and you need to scroll down to 1.5 times the screen to see them. By that I mean, My layout has more preference to other elements than comments, hence I limited them to 2. If in your case non-comment elements are less and comments are more important and you want to show all of them in the same layout, you better go with a ListView with 1st item(or header) being your non-comment part and rest all being comments.